# Pact JVM Junit Consumer Compilation Error

Tags: java, junit, consumer, pact

I am writing the Consumer Side Code for Pact using JVm-Junit library. However at the line :
MockProviderConfig config = MockProviderConfig.createDefault();
i am getting error "createDefault() is not undefined for the type MockProviderConfig"

What can I do to proceed.

My POM File looks like this :
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    Consumer_0805
    Consumer_080517
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    war

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
        <artifactId>pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Test Code :

```
package DSLDirectConsumerTest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.ConsumerPactBuilder;
import au.com.dius.pact.model.MockProviderConfig;
import au.com.dius.pact.model.MockProviderConfig$;
import au.com.dius.pact.model.PactConfig;
import au.com.dius.pact.model.PactFragment;
import au.com.dius.pact.model.RequestResponsePact;

public class DirectDSLConsumerPactTest {

    @Test
    public void testPact() {
        PactFragment pactFragment = ConsumerPactBuilder.consumer("Some Consumer").hasPactWith("Some Provider")
                .uponReceiving("a request to say Hello").path("/hello").method("POST").body("{\"name\": \"harry\"}")
                .willRespondWith().status(200).body("{\"hello\": \"harry\"}").toFragment();

        MockProviderConfig.createDefault();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the test code that is giving the error?

Comment: You can also try the latest version, which is 3.3.8

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Posted the test code.

Comment: Hi updating the version to 3.3.8 resolved the error! Thank you sooo much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 3.3.8, the `MockProviderConfig` class is a groovy class, so can be accessed normally.

Prior to version 3.3.0, it was both a Scala Singleton Object and Class, so you would need to access it appropriately as per calling Scala classes from Java.

As `createDefault()` is defined on the companion singleton object, the correct way to refer to it is:

`MockProviderConfig$.MODULE$.createDefault();`